# How to use MySql with ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, database

I have learned MySql in my school, but on CMD Prompt. Since i want to use that knowledge and want to create a GUI program in ruby (NOT A RUBY-ON-RAILS PROJECT) which use MySql commands like:

`SHOW DATABASES;`
`USE DATABASE ruby;`
`SELECT * FROM TABLE staff;`
`CREATE TABLE STUDENT(Rollno integer, Class integer);`
`INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(32, 12);`
`SHOW TABLES;`
`DROP TABLE STUDENT;`
etc. and etc...

but i am unable to find about that,
i have found mysql2 gemfile but it doesn't supports the command in my code, in

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(hostname: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: '1234', database: 'ruby')

list = client.query("SHOW TABLES")
list.each do |item|
    puts item
end
```

> No output and I'm just frustrated

Please give Suggestions

**WITH THE CONTIBUTION OF @URSUS, WE HAVE SOLVED THIS, WE RECHECKED THE `MySql GEMFILE` AND RECHECK THE `Table in Database` AND USE `irb`**

look over at this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19YUhmcLeMJn9aNEjM0bQNjpHIWrPZ0RX

Comment: Ideally you'd use a database layer like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) at the absolute least. The `mysql2` driver is pretty feeble. This code won't produce output unless you have tables defined in that database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the query. This query works for me.

`client.query("SHOW TABLES FROM DB")` DB being your database.

In your connection string you are specifying a database to connect to, so I don't believe you will be able to run `SHOW DATABASES`. Try removing the DB from the connection string.